# Pandas merge columns in some rows based on value in another column to deal with non-uniform csv data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a csv file that has an uneven number of columns in it. In one column is a number which indicates how many extra columns that row contains. This column is "num_servers" and is an integer. Following this column is one server, and one port column for each num_server, i.e. "host_0", "port_0", "host_1", "port_1" for a num_server = 2.

I want to join these columns where there is data, i.e. server,port and fill with None/Nan where there is none so that I have a uniform dataframe with only the columns in the middle containing Nones and end up with a dataframe.

An example of the csv:

```
sym1,exch,3,server_a,port_a,server_a,port_b,server_f,port_f,info1,info2,info3
sym2,exch,1,server_a,port_a,info1,info2,info3
sym3,exch,0,info1,info2,info3
sym4,exch,2,server_a,port_a,server_d,port_c,info1,info2,info3
```

The dictionary of the pandas dataframe that I would need is:

```
d = {"a": ["sym1", "sym2", "sym3", "sym4"], "b": ["blah", "blah", "blah", "blah"], "num_servers": [3, 1, 0, 2], "loc_0": ["server_a,port_a", "server_a,port_a", None, "server_a,port_a"], "loc_1": ["server_a,port_b", None, None, "server_d,port_c"], "loc_2": ["server_f,port_f", None, None, None], "info_1": ["info_1", "info_1", "info_1", "info_1"], "info_2": ["info_2", "info_2", "info_2", "info_2"], "info_3": ["info_3", "info_3", "info_3", "info_3"]}
```

When it's at the end of the file it is easy to loop from the first column until the end because every column without a server already has Nones, but I don't know how to handle it in the middle. Re-writing the config file is not an option sadly.

Comment: What is that you need as output? A dataframe or dictionary? Could you make it clear. Additionally, I would request you to reconstruct both the question and title, as they are not very clear.

Comment: I require a dataframe but the dictionary was an easy way to display the output. Sure can try to rephrase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the csv module to parse the file because it can easily handle a variable number of fields. Code could be:

```
with open('file.csv') as fd:
    rd = csv.reader(fd)
    data = []                       # will build a list of records as dicts
    mx = 0
    for row in rd:
        num_servers = int(row[2])
        if num_servers > mx:        # keep the max number of servers
            mx = num_servers
        # build one record
        d = {'a': row[0], 'b': row[1], 'num_servers': num_servers,
             'info1': row[-3], 'info2': row[-2], 'info3': row[-3]}
        for i in range(num_servers):
            d['loc_' + str(i)] = '{},{}'.format(row[3 + i * 2], row[4 + i * 2])
        data.append(d)              # add the record to the list

cols = ['a', 'b', 'num_servers']    # build the list of columns
cols.extend('loc_' + str(i) for i in range(mx))
cols.extend(('info1', 'info2', 'info3'))
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols) # done...
```

With the sample file, it gives:

```
      a     b  num_servers            loc_0            loc_1            loc_2  info1  info2  info3
0  sym1  exch            3  server_a,port_a  server_a,port_b  server_f,port_f  info1  info2  info1
1  sym2  exch            1  server_a,port_a              NaN              NaN  info1  info2  info1
2  sym3  exch            0              NaN              NaN              NaN  info1  info2  info1
3  sym4  exch            2  server_a,port_a  server_d,port_c              NaN  info1  info2  info1
```

Comment: This works wonderfully, typo on the last "info3" should be -1 but otherwise works brilliantly